# TASM: Can't locate file

Tags: assembly, tasm

Can't check the program I wrote because of the error **Fatal** Command line: "Can't locate file". The only questions I found were talking about variables' names, but they are definitely don't contain more than 6/8 symbols.

That's the very first program of mine, and I would be happy to find solution.

I tried to change the file's and variables' names. It didn't help. 
Sorry if the code is awful.

```
.model small
.stack
.data

s1 db 10, ?, 10 dup (?)
s2 db 10, 13, "You are amazing", 10, 13, "$"
el db 10, 13, "$"

.code
mov ax, @data 
mov ds, ax

mov ah, 0ah
lea dx, s1
int 21h

mov bl, s1
mov bh, 0

mov AL, s1[bx-2]
mov s2, AL

mov AL, s1[bx-2]
mov s2, AL

mov AL, s1[bx-2]
mov s2, AL

mov AL, s1[bx+1]
mov s2, AL

mov s2, "$"
mov s1, "$"

mov ah, 9
lea dx, s1
int 21h

mov ah, 9
lea dx, el
int 21h

mov ah, 9
lea sx, s2
int 21h

mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
end
```

Expected output:
second-to-last symbol of the introduced line 
(s1) to be copied in the 2s three times and the first symbol to be copied once.

Comment: Since your question is about running TASM on your file, not the contents of the code inside the file, your [mcve] needs to include more details about what filename your code is in and how exactly your ran TASM.  (Your code looks buggy, BTW, e.g. 5 writes to the same byte location (`s2`), so all the earlier copies are overwritten.  Perhaps you wanted to write to `s2+4`?)

Comment: The filename is "dasha.asm". Perhaps the code is really buggy, still I can't check it. I've tried to run the TASM via Dosbox (TASM 1.4 for Windows), typing "tasm dasha.asm".

Comment: Are you running that command from the same directory where the file is?  Does `dir dasha.asm` show it?

Comment: The command you wrote answers with "File dasha.asm not found". Anyway, I don't get it because file is located in the map "TASM" with apps and created automatically "dasha.map"

Comment: Find your file and CD there.  I haven't used TASM, but presumably it needs a correct path to your file.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know the reason it didn't work with the code written in Notepad, but as soon as I tried to do this with CodeBlocks, it succeeded.

Comment: You should probably ditch TASM for something more modern like NASM.